# [Laravel]: SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel

Building a Laravel project (v. 5.4) When I run `php artisan migrate` I get the following error message:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR: no schema has been selected
to create in (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" serial primary key not
null, "migration" varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null))
```

This just started happening now, whereas I've previously made a model and accompanying migration without incident in this very project, and have not changed my .env file or the config/database.php file since the initial setup that worked. I thought it might have something to do with being the wrong postgresql user, but I logged in to the CLI and `SET ROLE` to the owner of the database in question. No effect.

Comment: make sure your database has a schema named "public" which is the default schema in laravel with PostgreSQL
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: Currently my schema is set as:

    schema => env('DB_PGSQL_SCHEMA', 'public'),

in my database.php file. In my .env file I have
    DB_PGSQL_SCHEMA=fes

This worked for me on a previous migration, and just recently stopped working without me altering anything in these files. Should I still create a schema named 'public' in this case, or should it be 'fes'?

EDIT: It already had the 'public' schema, but creating 'fes' caused the migration to work. Thank you!

Comment: Did you found any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

sometimes I got this problem, in my case I solved it by commenting in the php.ini file the clear line that you need to change according to the bank you are using

```
;extension = pdo_pgsql
```

to

```
extension = pdo_pgsql
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your `.env` in placed. If not do

```
mv .env.example .env
```

and update following to your liking

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the schema name to my table and that works for me. It was `table` and now it's `public.table`.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php

sudo apt-get install php-pgsql

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

if your schema name is not "public" just rename it "public"