# How to define schema migration Laravel Postgres?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration

Im using a multitenant package in Laravel called [Laravel Tenancy](https://laravel-tenancy.com) and i change the setting to work with SCHEMA, every tenant has your schema right?

Well i'm using postgres and I'd like to change 'public' the default schema, i'd like to use maindatabase.

I have changed it in:

```
'connections' => [
        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'maindatabase',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
]
```

But when I execute **php artisan migrate** i have this error:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in at character 14 (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" serial primary key not null, "migration" varchar(255) not null, "batch" integer not null))`

How can I fix it? Thank you

Comment: see here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928237/laravel-sqlstate3f000-invalid-schema-name)

Comment: There's no solution in this reference :(

Comment: do maindatabase schema already exist?

Comment: Yep..it exist @dparoli

Comment: Make sure you have all USAGE privilege to that schema.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you @dparoli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have all USAGE privilege to that schema, i.e.:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA maindatabase TO your_username;
```